# Making sorting discoverable on a table with no default sort

Tags: gui-design, tables, sort

We have a table that orders results of clients (can be searched on name, address, email, phone, etc.) based on an algorithm, so there isn't a "default" sort we can mark with an arrow to indicate the table is sortable. However, there are two columns that are sortable, but you can only see a sort arrow indicator after you discover that and sort one of them. What is the best way to make this discoverable?

Answer (score 0):

##### Tell them with text, or show them with a control.

I don't know what the rest of your UI looks like, but if you need to make it clear, you could try a couple of approaches.

- **A: UI text** can be small, and live above the table, telling them what's possible.
- **B: Sort control**, starting with your applications 'default' (a tricky word here, I know), can show them that a sort is possible. By using the control, the user can always go back to 'default' (meaning your applications algo sort), which might be helpful(?).

[image]